# Java - printing random word

Tags: java

I'm having problems with an exercise. I need to print five random words, between min and max letters.

This is what I've done:

```
package Vjezba;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

import java.util.*;

public class String2 extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run () {
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        String a = randomWord();
        println(a);
    }

}

private String randomWord() {
    int a = rgen.nextInt(MIN_LETTER, MAX_LETTER);
    for (int x=0; x<a; x++){
        String niz = "";
        char c = randomChar();
        niz += 'c';
    }
    return niz;

}



private char randomChar(){
    return (char) rgen.nextInt('a', 'z');
}

private static RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
private static int MIN_LETTER = 3;
private static int MAX_LETTER = 10;
    }
```

I have problems with returning String. Dunno how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "have problems"? Are you getting an exception? Is nothing being returned?

Comment: +1 for asking help after you are stuck, and not asking us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore my comment, I hadn't woken up yet. Your randomWord() has a scope issue; you're declaring your String variable inside of your `for` loop and then trying to return it after the loop ends - I imagine you're getting a compile error. Modify it so that the empty String declaration is before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 5):

You're declaring your `String` inside your for loop; every time it loops you get a new (empty) String. You're also adding the character 'c', not the contents of your `char c`

```
String niz = "";
for (int x=0; x<a; x++){
    //String niz = "";
    char c = randomChar();
    niz += c; // c not 'c'
}
```

And while in this trivial case it doesn't really matter, a `String` in java is immutable - it can't be changed. Every time you do `niz += c` it creates a new string. Any time you're building a string you want to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder niz = new StringBuilder();
for (int x=0; x<a; x++){
    char c = randomChar();
    niz.append(c);
}
return niz.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

`niz += 'c';` should be `niz = niz + c;` or `niz +=  c;` [personally I prefer the first, since it is more clear that the object is not modified but the reference is changed].

also, `niz` should be declared out of the loop's scope [before the `for` line].

```
String niz = "";
for (int x=0; x<a; x++){
    char c = randomChar();
    niz = niz + c;
}
return niz;
```

you might want to use [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) if performance is an issue, but I don't think it is the case in here.

Comment: `+=` works just fine (though, not really as it creates a new `String` every time the same as `niz = niz + c;`)

Comment: @Brian Roach: Read my answer, I said I prefer it for clarity, not that it doesn't work, the "doesn't work" part refers to 'adding' `'c'` instead of `c`.

Comment: Yes, now that you've edited it it does say that. And it notes the problem with the String being declared in the loop and the StringBuilder from my answer ...

Comment: @Brian Roach: my answer was editted 8 mins ago, yours 2 mins ago. your comment is 6 mins ago, stop trolling.

Comment: Care to look at the edit and see the only thing I added was `// c not 'c'` or do you want to keep playing this game?

Comment: @Brian Roach: you can also look at my edit and see I only added the code snap and changed object is changed -> reference is changed. I'm done with this discussion. No point to feed the troll.